# tar with ssh: what happens if creation speed is higher than network speed?

Tags: networking, tar, io

I'm concerned what will happen if speed of **source read + stream create** operations gets higher than underlying network protocol speed?

Is **tar** going to *create and cache data locally before it is transported over network*? If so, is there any sane way of preventing this **?**

The scenario is like:

```
tar cf '/path/to/dir' | pigz -p 3 | ssh user@remotemachine.tld "cat > /backup/data.tar.gz"
```

and the host machine (the one that issues `tar cf` command) **should not** get additional data on it's local storage.

Comment: Do you expect something harmful to happen in this scenario? Why do you want to prevent any possible caching? Is there an actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @ilkkachu yes. Running out of available space. The machine cannot afford using of local disk space for this operation.

Comment: @ilkkachu so, is there any possible caching that should be prevented? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First over ssh you have compression with will mitigate from one side your concerns.

Second the pipe mechanism will "hold" the source until you have transferred all the information in the pipe.

Comment: to hold the source... to hold the source created (thus, cached somewhere on local disk) or to hold reading + creating operation until previous is transported? The big difference to me. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Hold writing (to the pipe) operation. Pipes do not use caching on disk